# How can i convert scraping script as web-service?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to build a api that accepts a string and returns html code.

Here is my scraping code that i want as a web-service.

> Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
import requests
import time

url = "https://www.pnrconverter.com/"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
string = "3 PS 232 M 03FEB 7 JFKKBP HK2 1230A 420P 03FEB E 
PS/JPIX8U"
button = 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='dataInputChild']")
button.send_keys(string) #accept string
button.submit()
time.sleep(5)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')
html = soup.find('div',class_="main-content") #returns html
print(html)
```

Can anyone tell me the best possible solution to wrap up my code as a api/web-service.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: Probably use their API to get a JSON response rather than trying to screen scrape it out of their webpage. Then you don't have to host your own service at all.

Comment: @pcurry how can i use their API for scraping purpose. can you guide me, i didn't write API code before?

Comment: I haven't looked at it... but [this seems like the logical place to start](https://www.pnrconverter.com/api-introduction) after googling `pnrconverter.com api`

Comment: @mrfreester how can i start because i didn't know how to start

Comment: It feels like we're doing your homework for you...

Comment: @pcurry No, i am trying to complete my project.

Comment: this is too broad, look up how to use their API and then look up how to make http requests in python. if you were able to manage writing this code snippet then you can probably do that as well if you try, that way you will learn!

Answer (score 1):

There's no best possible solution in general, because a solution has to fit the problem and the available resources.

Right now it seems like you're trying to wrap someone else's website. If that's the problem you're actually trying to solve, and you want to give credit, you should probably just forward people to their site. Have your site return a `302 Redirect` with their URL in the `Location` field in your header.

If what you're trying to do is get the response from this one sample check you have hardcoded, and and make that result available, I would suggest you put it in a static file behind `nginx`.

If what you're trying to do is use their backend to turn itineraries you have into responses you can return, you can do that by using their backend API, once that becomes available. Read the documentation, use the `requests` library to hit the API endpoint that you want, and get the JSON result back, and format it to your desires.

If you're trying to duplicate their site by making yourself a man-in-the-middle, that may be illegal and you should reconsider what you're doing.

For hosting purposes, you need to figure out how often  your API will be hit. You can probably start on `Heroku` or something similar fairly easily, and scale up if you need to. You'll probably want WebObj or Flask or something similar sitting at the website where you intend to host this application. You can use those to process what I presume will be a simple request into the string you wish to hit their API with.

Answer (score 0):

I am the owner of PNR Converter, so I can shed some light on your attempt to scrape content from our site. Unfortunately scraping from PNR Converter is not recommended. We are developing an API which looks like it would suit your needs, and should be ready in the not too distant future. If you contact us through the site we would be happy to work with you should you wish to use PNR Converter legitimately. PNR Converter gets at least one complete update per year and as such we change all the code on a regular basis. We also monitor all requests to our site, and we will block any requests which are deemed as improper usage. Our filter has already picked up your IP address (ends in 250.144) as potential misuse.

Like I said, should you wish to work with us at PNR Converter legitimately and not scrape our content then we would be happy to do so! please keep checking https://www.pnrconverter.com/api-introduction for information relating to our API.

We are releasing a backend upgrade this weekend, which will have a different HTML structure, and dynamically named elements which will cause a serious issue for web scrapers!

Comment: I am not doing scraping.